# Python: Problema al acceder con índices a un elemento individual de una lista de listas

Tags: python, lista

Estoy escribiendo un sencillo programa de hundir la flota.

Primero creo un tablero cuadrado, en la forma de una lista de listas, a continuación, relleno todas las casillas del tablero con 'O', luego extraigo una fila y una columna aleatorias para ubicar al barco en el tablero; y aquí viene el problema:

Cuando quiero sustituir la 'O' en esa casilla aleatoria por una 'B' que representa al barco, no solo me cambia una casilla, sino todas las filas del tablero. El problema está en la línea `tablero[filaBarco][columnaBarco] = 'B'`. ¿Qué está pasando? Si hago lo mismo fuera del programa, en el Shell, todo funciona bien, pero en el programa me falla.

Adjunto el código:

```
import random

def imprimeTablero(tablero):
    print('')
    for fila in tablero:
        filaImpresa = ''
        for i in fila:
            filaImpresa = filaImpresa + i + ' '
        print(filaImpresa)
    print('')

# PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL.
print('Juego de hundir la flota.')

# Creamos una lista vacía para alojar el tablero.
# El tablero será una lista de listas.
tablero = []
print('¿De qué tamaño quieres el tablero?')
print('Escribe un entero N para un tablero de NxN, o pulsa INTRO para 5x5')
tam = input()
if tam == '':
    tam = 5
else:
    tam = int(tam)

# Rellenamos el tablero con 'O' en todas sus casillas.
fila = []
for i in range(tam):
    fila = fila + ['O']
for j in range(tam):
    tablero.append(fila)

# Imprimimos el tablero inicial.
imprimeTablero(tablero)

# Ubicamos el barco en una localización aleatoria del tablero.
filaBarco = random.randint(0, len(tablero)-1)
columnaBarco = random.randint(0, len(tablero)-1)
print(tablero)
print(filaBarco)
print(columnaBarco)
tablero[filaBarco][columnaBarco] = 'B' # Qué pasa??
print(tablero)
imprimeTablero(tablero)
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema lo tienes en la forma en que creas el tablero, aquí:

```
fila = []
for i in range(tam):
    fila = fila + ['O']
for j in range(tam):
    tablero.append(fila)
```

Como puedes ver, primero creas una `fila` y luego creas el tablero añadiendo varias veces **la misma fila**. Todas las filas del tablero son referencia al mismo objeto `fila` creado anteriormente.

Así que no es de extrañar que cuando modificas una casilla en una cualquiera de las filas te aparezcan todas modificadas, ya que ¡todas las filas son en realidad la misma!

La solución es usar un bucle anidado para crear cada una de las filas como un objeto serparado:

```
for j in range(tam):
    fila = []
    for i in range(tam):
        fila = fila + ['O']
    tablero.append(fila)
```

Nota: Puedes abreviar esos bucles a una sola línea, usando una comprensión de listas:

```
tablero = [ ['O' for i in range(tam)] for j in range(tam) ]
```